# Mapping naming convention for parameters in actions for asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a razor view with that does

```
 <form asp-action="Action">
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.Name)
</form>
```

when submitting the form I would like to get the name of the user as a parameter,
but with `user`, `userName`, `user_Name` the property doesnt get mapped.

What is asp.net core expecting as a name so that it gets mapped correctly?

```
public ActionResult Action(MyModel m) // not desired

public ActionResult Action(string name) // tried userName and user_Name
{

}
```

Comment: Does aspnet core not create a fixed ID in the generated html that you could check? That's obviously lame when you need to do it for 1000 vars, but might give you a pointer to what _could_ work.

Comment: It does. The issue is that the OP is using one thing to generate the form fields with and wants to bind to something completely different after posting. Obviously the assumption is that you're going to actually accept the thing you're binding to, so the fields names are generated accordingly.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel yes but the name is User.Name and I can obviously not name the variable that way. So I tought it might be user_name or userName or something like that. Kirk's solution did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` of the input being generated in this scenario is `User.Name`. You can't call your parameter `User.Name`, of course, as this isn't a valid C# identifier. A simple way to make this work is to instruct the Model-Binder to use `User.Name` for your `name` parameter using the `FromForm` attribute. e.g.:

```
public ActionResult Action([FromForm(Name = "User.Name")] string name)
{

}
```

With this approach, `name` can be anything you like.